# How to change a variable in a Class with dot notation?

Tags: kotlin, oop

```
class MyClass(me : String) {
        var name :String = "My Name"
}
```

Why can't i do

```
MyClass.name = "New Name"
```

I want to change the variable value in the main class, And i don't want to create an instance to do this. Is it possible in kotlin?

Creating instance and changing that value obviously doesn't change the value of main class, So i am mainly looking for a way to change the variable from the main class using the dot notation ,

Is it possible?

Comment: What you’re describing doesn’t make sense. The variable only has a value in each instance of the class. Without an instance of the class, you have nothing. There is no “main class”.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the *initial value* of `name`, for every subsequent `MyClass` instance you create?

Comment: Do you mean to have a static property?

Comment: In Kotlin, you can’t change the value of a non-static variable in a class without creating an instance of that class.  The name variable in your class is an instance variable, meaning it belongs to an instance of the class, not the class itself.

Comment: @esQmo Yes! Thats what i want to do, can i create a variable thats common to both the main class and the instance.

Comment: Sure, there is already an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, to accomplish this just put your variable into a companion object like this:

```kotlin
class MyClass(me : String) {
  companion object {
    var name = "My Name"
  }
}
```

In your current implementation, `name` is an instance property, but you clearly want it to be a static property of your class.